# Use ES6 array methods reduce, map, and or filter to go through array to find the asteroids that have the same year that comes up the most

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, methods, reduce

```
const data = {
asteroids: [
    { name: '1 Ceres', discoveryYear: 1801, orbitalPeriod: 1681.63 },
    { name: '6 Hebe', discoveryYear: 1847, orbitalPeriod: 1380.373 },
    { name: '47171 Lempo', discoveryYear: 1999, orbitalPeriod: 91678 },
    { name: '762 Pulcova', discoveryYear: 1913, orbitalPeriod: 2049.475 },
    { name: '4179 Toutatis', discoveryYear: 1989, orbitalPeriod: 1463.14 },
    { name: '50000 Quaoar', discoveryYear: 2002, orbitalPeriod: 104347.575 },
    { name: '2867 Šteins', discoveryYear: 1969, orbitalPeriod: 1327.3582 },
    { name: '5 Astraea', discoveryYear: 1845, orbitalPeriod: 1507.279 },
    { name: '5145 Pholus', discoveryYear: 1992, orbitalPeriod: 33711 },
    { name: '4769 Castalia', discoveryYear: 1989, orbitalPeriod: 400.428 },
    { name: '624 Hektor', discoveryYear: 1907, orbitalPeriod: 4358.521 },
    { name: '216 Kleopatra', discoveryYear: 1880, orbitalPeriod: 1707 },
    { name: '3753 Cruithne', discoveryYear: 1986, orbitalPeriod: 364.019 },
    { name: '3 Juno', discoveryYear: 1804, orbitalPeriod: 1593.926 },
    { name: '10 Hygiea', discoveryYear: 1849, orbitalPeriod: 2029.776 },
    { name: '21 Lutetia', discoveryYear: 1852, orbitalPeriod: 1387.902 },
    { name: '253 Mathilde', discoveryYear: 1885, orbitalPeriod: 1572.491 },
    { name: '7 Iris', discoveryYear: 1847, orbitalPeriod: 1346.628 },
    { name: '433 Eros', discoveryYear: 1898, orbitalPeriod: 643.219 },
    { name: '90377 Sedna', discoveryYear: 2003, orbitalPeriod: 4154395 },
    { name: '10199 Chariklo', discoveryYear: 1997, orbitalPeriod: 23084 },
    { name: '87 Sylvia', discoveryYear: 1866, orbitalPeriod: 2381.639 },
    { name: '90482 Orcus', discoveryYear: 2004, orbitalPeriod: 89606 },
    { name: '5335 Damocles', discoveryYear: 1991, orbitalPeriod: 14880.9 },
    { name: '8 Flora', discoveryYear: 1847, orbitalPeriod: 1192.956 },
    { name: '2060 Chiron', discoveryYear: 1977, orbitalPeriod: 18429 },
    { name: '5261 Eureka', discoveryYear: 1990, orbitalPeriod: 686.829 },
    { name: '588 Achilles', discoveryYear: 1906, orbitalPeriod: 4320.803 },
    { name: '28978 Ixion', discoveryYear: 2001, orbitalPeriod: 90717 },
    { name: '9 Metis', discoveryYear: 1848, orbitalPeriod: 1346.815 },
    { name: '7066 Nessus', discoveryYear: 1993, orbitalPeriod: 44561 },
    { name: '25143 Itokawa', discoveryYear: 1998, orbitalPeriod: 556.38 },
    { name: '10370 Hylonome', discoveryYear: 1995, orbitalPeriod: 44561 },
    { name: '45 Eugenia', discoveryYear: 1857, orbitalPeriod: 1638.654 },
    { name: '(308933) 2006 SQ372', discoveryYear: 2006, orbitalPeriod: 11800000 },
    { name: '2 Pallas', discoveryYear: 1802, orbitalPeriod: 1685.927 },
    { name: '8405 Asbolus', discoveryYear: 1995, orbitalPeriod: 27796 },
    { name: '20000 Varuna', discoveryYear: 2000, orbitalPeriod: 103440 },
    { name: '4 Vesta', discoveryYear: 1807, orbitalPeriod: 1325.886 },
    { name: '243 Ida', discoveryYear: 1884, orbitalPeriod: 1767.564 },
    { name: '951 Gaspra', discoveryYear: 1916, orbitalPeriod: 1199.479 },
    { name: '15760 Albion', discoveryYear: 1992, orbitalPeriod: 105757 },
    { name: 'Arrokoth', discoveryYear: 2014, orbitalPeriod: 107847 },
    { name: '101955 Bennu', discoveryYear: 1999, orbitalPeriod: 436.604 }
  ],
};
```

here is my code that I am trying.

```
function getGreatestDiscoveryYear(data) {
  return data.asteroids.reduce((acc, val)) => acc[val.discoveryYear] = 
    (acc[val.discoveryYear] || 0) + 1, {});  
}
```

I would like to go through each object in the array. Then I would like to see which asteroids have the same years and which year is the most common amongst all of the years that exist.
I keep running into the problem of just getting a new array of the objects.
The result I am looking for is the year 1847.

Comment: Where is your code that you have the problem with? What is the expected output for this example data?

Comment: @trincot there is that a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `reduce` callback you need to return the accumulator, but your code returns the assigned count.

Then after the `reduce` call has finished there still remains to identify the entry with the highest count:

```js
const data = {asteroids: [{ name: '1 Ceres', discoveryYear: 1801, orbitalPeriod: 1681.63 },{ name: '6 Hebe', discoveryYear: 1847, orbitalPeriod: 1380.373 },{ name: '47171 Lempo', discoveryYear: 1999, orbitalPeriod: 91678 },{ name: '762 Pulcova', discoveryYear: 1913, orbitalPeriod: 2049.475 },{ name: '4179 Toutatis', discoveryYear: 1989, orbitalPeriod: 1463.14 },{ name: '50000 Quaoar', discoveryYear: 2002, orbitalPeriod: 104347.575 },{ name: '2867 Šteins', discoveryYear: 1969, orbitalPeriod: 1327.3582 },{ name: '5 Astraea', discoveryYear: 1845, orbitalPeriod: 1507.279 },{ name: '5145 Pholus', discoveryYear: 1992, orbitalPeriod: 33711 },{ name: '4769 Castalia', discoveryYear: 1989, orbitalPeriod: 400.428 },{ name: '624 Hektor', discoveryYear: 1907, orbitalPeriod: 4358.521 },{ name: '216 Kleopatra', discoveryYear: 1880, orbitalPeriod: 1707 },{ name: '3753 Cruithne', discoveryYear: 1986, orbitalPeriod: 364.019 },{ name: '3 Juno', discoveryYear: 1804, orbitalPeriod: 1593.926 },{ name: '10 Hygiea', discoveryYear: 1849, orbitalPeriod: 2029.776 },{ name: '21 Lutetia', discoveryYear: 1852, orbitalPeriod: 1387.902 },{ name: '253 Mathilde', discoveryYear: 1885, orbitalPeriod: 1572.491 },{ name: '7 Iris', discoveryYear: 1847, orbitalPeriod: 1346.628 },{ name: '433 Eros', discoveryYear: 1898, orbitalPeriod: 643.219 },{ name: '90377 Sedna', discoveryYear: 2003, orbitalPeriod: 4154395 },{ name: '10199 Chariklo', discoveryYear: 1997, orbitalPeriod: 23084 },{ name: '87 Sylvia', discoveryYear: 1866, orbitalPeriod: 2381.639 },{ name: '90482 Orcus', discoveryYear: 2004, orbitalPeriod: 89606 },{ name: '5335 Damocles', discoveryYear: 1991, orbitalPeriod: 14880.9 },{ name: '8 Flora', discoveryYear: 1847, orbitalPeriod: 1192.956 },{ name: '2060 Chiron', discoveryYear: 1977, orbitalPeriod: 18429 },{ name: '5261 Eureka', discoveryYear: 1990, orbitalPeriod: 686.829 },{ name: '588 Achilles', discoveryYear: 1906, orbitalPeriod: 4320.803 },{ name: '28978 Ixion', discoveryYear: 2001, orbitalPeriod: 90717 },{ name: '9 Metis', discoveryYear: 1848, orbitalPeriod: 1346.815 },{ name: '7066 Nessus', discoveryYear: 1993, orbitalPeriod: 44561 },{ name: '25143 Itokawa', discoveryYear: 1998, orbitalPeriod: 556.38 },{ name: '10370 Hylonome', discoveryYear: 1995, orbitalPeriod: 44561 },{ name: '45 Eugenia', discoveryYear: 1857, orbitalPeriod: 1638.654 },{ name: '(308933) 2006 SQ372', discoveryYear: 2006, orbitalPeriod: 11800000 },{ name: '2 Pallas', discoveryYear: 1802, orbitalPeriod: 1685.927 },{ name: '8405 Asbolus', discoveryYear: 1995, orbitalPeriod: 27796 },{ name: '20000 Varuna', discoveryYear: 2000, orbitalPeriod: 103440 },{ name: '4 Vesta', discoveryYear: 1807, orbitalPeriod: 1325.886 },{ name: '243 Ida', discoveryYear: 1884, orbitalPeriod: 1767.564 },{ name: '951 Gaspra', discoveryYear: 1916, orbitalPeriod: 1199.479 },{ name: '15760 Albion', discoveryYear: 1992, orbitalPeriod: 105757 },{ name: 'Arrokoth', discoveryYear: 2014, orbitalPeriod: 107847 },{ name: '101955 Bennu', discoveryYear: 1999, orbitalPeriod: 436.604 }],};

let year = +Object.entries(data.asteroids.reduce((acc, {name, discoveryYear}) =>
    (acc[discoveryYear] = (acc[discoveryYear] || 0) + 1, acc)
, {})).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0];

console.log(year);
```